# Save IList<T> or IQueryable<T> to Excel - C#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5

I'm generating a report via Linq to SQL and displaying it on the website.

I need to save the report in MS Excel (or .csv) and email it to user.

Any ideas on how to save it as Excel or .csv ?

.NET 3.5 / C#

EDIT:

the [Gridview hack](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html) works perfect. If you use AJAX on the page, make sure you add a PostBaseTrigger to your Update Panel to cause FULL POSTBACK, it won't work otherwise.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export Grid" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've also found  a [Library to Generate Excel XML Workbooks in .NET](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/), however it's not as simple as accepted solution.

Comment: More details would be helpful. Are you having a specific problem? What error did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [gridview hack](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html) is the simplest solution I've found.

Comment: That way works great for a small result set but for larger ones, LINQtoCSV is definitely a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

Go to [this article on **LINQtoCSV** on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx).  Then open the source code in VS and comment out line 201 in FieldMapper.cs to fix a bug that mangles the column ordering:

```
//Array.Sort(m_IndexToInfo);
```

Recompile and you're good to go.

(I found that from the comments of the article)

Then to use:

```
CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
{
    SeparatorChar = '\t', // tab delimited
    FirstLineHasColumnNames = false // no column names in first record
};

CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

cc.Write(
    YOUR_IQUERYABLE_RESULT_HERE,
    "filename.csv",
    outputFileDescription);
```

I made a simplified IQueryable`<T`>.WriteToFile(path) extension method but I don't have it on this machine.